# Modifying and passing global variables

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having trouble modifying a global variable in a callback.

I need to reload the data from a file every hour. It works fine if I use `readFileSync` but not if I use the normal `readFile`:

```
var MY_GLOBAL = {};

fs.readFile("some_path", function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    MY_GLOBAL.some_name = data;
    });

setInterval(function() {
    fs.readFile("some_path", function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        MY_GLOBAL.some_name = data;
        }
    }, 60 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

I have another module named `router.js` which contains all the routing for my application.

I call it using: `router(app, MY_GLOBAL)`.

My issue is that although `MY_GLOBAL` gets set in the `readFile` callback, it doesn't update in the router. I need to access the updated data every hour.

Comment: Sorry, but this is really, really bad code.  You're trying to use the value of an asynchronous function by stuffing it into a global variable.  Very bad way to code.  It cannot be made predictable because you don't know when you can use the global (e.g. when the async function has finished).  You should use the value of `fs.readFile()` in the callback itself, not stuff it into a global and hope someone else can guess the correct timing to use it from the global.  This is async programming basics.  You MUST learn this in order to program in node.js.

Comment: How does `router` use `MY_GLOBAL`?

Comment: `MY_GLOBAL` is local to the module.  It is not a global variable.  Node modules are not at the top level.  If you want to share it with another module, you can create an accessor function for it and export it or there is a way to actually make it an actual global.  See http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html for more info.  All that aside, please read my first comment because stuff async results into a variable and hoping some other module can pick up that result is generally a bad way to program.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest several things to check.

First, I would double check that the callback function is executing for certain using `console.log` or `alert`.

I would also like to point out that objects are passed by reference in Javascript, which means that the object passed in to `router` is a reference to `MY_GLOBAL`, not a copy of `MY_GLOBAL`.  Where this can go wrong is if somewhere you reassigned MY_GLOBAL.  I would make sure that you did not reassign MY_GLOBAL anywhere.

Also, if `data` is an object (as opposed to a string, number, or boolean), you need to check that it doesn't get reassigned, either.  For example, if you read the value of MY_GLOBAL.some_name inside of `router`, it is possible that you could retain a reference to an old version after `data` is assigned to MY_GLOBAL.some_name.

Comment: `MY_GLOBAL` is not a global variable.  It's a top level module variable which is not global and is not directly visible by other modules.

Answer (score 0):

If its a global statement why not try to use the `module` keyword such a lot of people does with the `window`.

another thing. You want the function code to be executed every hour. you are putting one extra 60 multiplication into the second parameter. try this.

```
module.MY_GLOBAL = {};

var callbackFunction = function(){
  fs.readFile("some_path", function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    module.MY_GLOBAL.some_name = data;
  }
};
callbackFunction();
setInterval(callbackFunction , 60 * 60 * 1000); // 360000 == 1 hour
```